# Time code isn't returning the correct thing

Tags: java

I've got this code that is supposed to tell how much time has gone in the day given the hours, minutes, and AM/PM. It is supposed to run an invalid time format if the time isn't a real time ( 44:65 PM) but it is shooting that error back for every time I put in.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String time_inp;
        System.out.print("Enter the time in the format hours:minutes AM/PM : ");
        time_inp=sc.nextLine();
        String[] time = time_inp.split(":");
        int hours = Integer.valueOf(time[0]);
        String[] time1=time[1].split(" ");
        int minutes = Integer.valueOf(time1[0]);
        String ampm = time1[1];
        int new_hour=0,new_minutes=0;
        if((minutes>60)||(hours>12)||(!ampm.equals("AM"))||(!ampm.equals("PM")))
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Time Format");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(ampm.equals("AM"))
        {
            new_hour=hours;
            new_minutes=minutes;
        }
        else if(ampm.equals("PM"))
        {
            new_hour=12+hours;
            new_minutes=minutes;
        }
        System.out.println("Time elapsed : "+new_hour+" hours "+new_minutes+" minutes");
    }
}
```

Output for 1:30 PM should be

```
Time elapsed : 13 hours 30 minutes
```

Comment: A bit outside the scope of the question, but any reason why you're not leveraging Java's built-in time parsing functionality? [`LocalTIme.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-)

Comment: Common error: because the two checks are mutually exclusive, one check must be true, causing the error check to always be true and always taken: `(!ampm.equals("AM"))||(!ampm.equals("PM")`

Comment: Your condition logic is wrong. It says stop when either `ampm` is not AM or it's not PM. Well, if it's PM, it's not AM, and if it's AM, it's not PM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *if* condition is always evaluated to true

```
if((minutes>60)||(hours>12)||(!ampm.equals("AM"))||(!ampm.equals("PM")))
```

Have a look at the last two checks. Irrespective of what you enter (AM/PM) one of the will be true. Hence, the *if* block is always executed.

The correct one must be

```
if ((minutes > 60) || (hours > 12) || (!ampm.equals("AM") && (!ampm.equals("PM"))))
```

Comment: Yes, I temporarily reversed the sense of the test in my head, mea culpa.